# Can't create css,html... files in eclipse

Tags: css, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc

I'm working on a spring project and i want to add some css to my views
but css files are created (in the webapp folder) as Java source files:
so there is no auto-completion, it is unrecognized as a css file.

Here is how the css file appears:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What process are you going through to create your css files? I don't use Eclipse anymore but I believe I used the context menus `New > Other > Web > CSS` with no issues. Also what version of Eclipse are you using?

Comment: Hi Dean ,yes i use as you said the context menus New > Other > Web > CSS and i'm using the JAVA EE IDE eclipse Neon

Comment: Can you open the CSS file with the CSS editor via right-click and _Open With > ..._?

Comment: Yes, it s a normal css file, the problem is with the IDE i think

Comment: I don't think eclipse/sts has auto-complete for CSS files.  Possibly with a plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for anyone who has the same issue you can go to help -> eclipse marketplace search for html and install the tool u need, restart eclipse and it will work.

Answer (score 3):

This tool from Marketplace worked for me. Refer below images.

[Marketplace - Tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KF6qW.png),
[HTML - Project Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmxV7.png)